# Toggle search textbox on button click not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a textbox which should appear when I click on the button. But when I click on the button the page loads and textbox is not displayed in place. What could be the problem? Should I change the button `type` or should I use `preventDefault` so that the page does not load?

My code:

```js
$("#search-button").click(function(){
  $("#search").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.search-bar {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  /*padding: 2px 5px;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  color: white;
}
.btn-circle:hover{
  background-color: white !important;
  color: #00BCD4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search" style="display: none;">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-circle" type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me with this issue. And how to make the search button round? (Right now its round from right side only).

Thankyou

Comment: just remove '0' in  padding: 6px 0; and it's gonna be round ; )

Comment: @impregnablefiend it didnt work after removing 0 from padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
```

to:

```
<div class="input-group">
```

For your js you need to wrap it into document ready and prevent the default event:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#search-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#search").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.search-bar {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  /*padding: 2px 5px;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  color: white;
}
.btn-circle:hover{
  background-color: white !important;
  color: #00BCD4;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-circle" type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works but the textbox that appears should be inline, according to your code it shifts down the button.

Comment: @MannuNayyar  Move outside the input-group containing the button. Let me know.  Snippet updated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add `e.preventDefault();` in order to stop the page from refreshing.

```
$("#search-button").click(function(e){
    $("#search").slideToggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search-button").click(function(){
  $("#search").fadeIn();
$(this).parent().addClass('input-group-btn');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li>
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search" style="display:none;">
<div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="search-button">Go <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
```